# Reduce the set of input files dynamically during a snakemake run

Tags: snakemake

this is more of a technical question regarding the capabilities of snakemake. I was wondering whether it is possible to dynamically alter the set of input samples during a snakemake run.

The reason why I would like to do so is the following: Let's assume a set of sample associated bam files. The first rule determines the quality of each sample (based on the bam file), i.e. all input files are concerned. 
However, given specified criteria, only a subset of samples is considered as valid and should be processed further. So the next step (e.g. gene counting or something else) should only be done for the approved bam files, as shown in the minimal example below:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
   input: "results/gene_count.tsv"

rule a:
   input: expand( "data/{sample}.bam", sample=config['samples'])
   output: "results/list_of_qual_approved_samples.out"
   shell: '''command'''

rule b:
   input: expand( "data/{sample}.bam", sample=config['valid_samples'])
   output: "results/gene_count.tsv"
   shell: '''command'''
```

In this example, rule a would extend the configuration file with a list of valid sample names, even though I believe to know that this is not possible.

Of course, the straightforward solution would be to have two distinct inputs: 1.) all bam files and 2.) a file that lists all valid files. This would boil down to do the sample selection within the code of the rule.

```
rule alternative_b:
   input: 
      expand( "data/{sample}.bam", sample=config['samples']),
      "results/list_of_qual_approved_samples.out"
   output: "results/gene_count.tsv"
   shell: '''command'''
```

However, do you see a way to setup the rules such that the behavior of the first example can be achieved?

Many thanks in advance, 
Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, one that does not use "dynamic".

It's not that you do not know how many files you are going to use, but rather, you are only using a sub-set of the files you would be starting with. Since you are able to generate a "samples.txt" list of all the potential files, I'm going to assume you have a firm starting point.

I did something similar, where I have initial files that I want to process for validity, (in my case, I'm increasing the quality~sorting, indexing etc). I then want to ignore everything except my resultant file.

What I suggest, to avoid creating a secondary list of sample files, is to create a second directory of data (reBamDIR), data2 (BamDIR). In data2, you symlink over all the files that are valid. That way, Snake can just process EVERYTHING in the data2 directory. Makes moving down the pipeline easier, the pipeline can stop relying on sample lists, and it can just process everything using wildcards (much easier to code). This is possible becuase when I symlink I then standardize the names. I list the symlinked files in the output rule so Snakemake knows about them and then it can create the DAG.

```
`-- output
    |-- bam
    |   |-- Pfeiffer2.bam ->     /home/tboyarski/share/projects/tboyarski/gitRepo-LCR-BCCRC/Snakemake/buildArea/output/reBam/Pfeiffer2_realigned_sorted.bam
    |   `-- Pfeiffer2.bam.bai ->     /home/tboyarski/share/projects/tboyarski/gitRepo-LCR-    BCCRC/Snakemake/buildArea/output/reBam/Pfeiffer2_realigned_sorted.bam.bai
    |-- fastq
    |-- mPile
    |-- reBam
    |   |-- Pfeiffer2_realigned_sorted.bam
    |   `-- Pfeiffer2_realigned_sorted.bam.bai
```

In this case, all you need is a return value in your "validator", and a conditional operator to respond to it.

**I would argue you already have this somewhere, since you must be using conditionals in your validation step. Instead of using it to write the file name to a txt file, just symlink the file in a finalized location and keep going.**

My raw data is in reBamDIR.
The final data I store in BamDIR.
I only symlink the files from this stage in the pipeline over to bamDIR.
There are OTHER files in reBamDIR, but I don't want the rest of my pipeline to see them, so, I'm filtering them out.

I'm not exactly sure how to implement the "validator" and your conditional, as I do not know your situation, and I'm still learning too. Just trying to offer alternative perspectives//approaches.

```
from time import gmtime, strftime

rule indexBAM:
    input:
        expand("{outputDIR}/{reBamDIR}/{{samples}}{fileTAG}.bam", outputDIR=config["outputDIR"], reBamDIR=config["reBamDIR"], fileTAG=config["fileTAG"])
    output:
        expand("{outputDIR}/{reBamDIR}/{{samples}}{fileTAG}.bam.bai", outputDIR=config["outputDIR"], reBamDIR=config["reBamDIR"], fileTAG=config["fileTAG"]),
        expand("{outputDIR}/{bamDIR}/{{samples}}.bam.bai", outputDIR=config["outputDIR"], bamDIR=config["bamDIR"]),
        expand("{outputDIR}/{bamDIR}/{{samples}}.bam", outputDIR=config["outputDIR"], bamDIR=config["bamDIR"])
    params:
        bamDIR=config["bamDIR"],
        outputDIR=config["outputDIR"],
        logNAME="indexBAM." + strftime("%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
    log:
        "log/" + config["reBamDIR"]
    shell:
        "samtools index {input} {output[0]} " \
        " 2> {log}/{params.logNAME}.stderr " \
        "&& ln -fs $(pwd)/{output[0]} $(pwd)/{params.outputDIR}/{params.bamDIR}/{wildcards.samples}.bam.bai " \
        "&& ln -fs $(pwd)/{input} $(pwd)/{params.outputDIR}/{params.bamDIR}/{wildcards.samples}.bam"
```

Comment: Even though I think the intrinsic "dynamic" functionality of snakemake would allow to resolve my issue as stated by @pereirahugo, your proposed workflow works perfectly for my needs. I like the idea to create symlinks to avoid copying big BAM-files and setting a naming scheme at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: Additional note: After I played around a bit with this problem, I think there is no way around using dynamic in some way or the other. So finally, I ended up using @TBojarski's suggestion but in conjunction with  the **dynamic flag** to make snakemake aware of an unknown number of input files.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer that could be interesting.

At first I thought that it wasn't possible to do it. Because `Snakemake needs the final files` at the end. So you can't just separate a set of files without knowing the separation at the beginning.

But then I tried with the function **dynamic**. With the function **dynamic** you don't have to know the amount of files which will be created​ by the rule.

So I coded this :

```
rule all:
   input: "results/gene_count.tsv"

rule a:
   input: expand( "data/{sample}.bam", sample=config['samples'])
   output: dynamic("data2/{foo}.bam")
   shell: 
     './bloup.sh "{input}"'

rule b:
   input: dynamic("data2/{foo}.bam")
   output: touch("results/gene_count.tsv")
   shell: '''command'''
```

Like in your first example the snakefile wants to produce a file named `results/gene_count.ts`.

The `rule a` takes **all samples** from configuration file. This rule execute a script that chooses​ the files to create. I have `4 initial` files (geneA, geneB, geneC, geneD) and it `only touches two` for the output (geneA and geneD files) in a second repertory. There is no problem with the **dynamic** function.

The `rule b` takes all the dynamics files created by the `rule a`. So you just have to produce the **results/gene_count.tsv**. I just touched​ it in the example.

Here is the `log of Snakemake` for more information :

```
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       a
        1       all
        1       b
        3

rule a:
    input: data/geneA.bam, data/geneB.bam, data/geneC.bam, data/geneD.bam
    output: data2/{*}.bam (dynamic)

Subsequent jobs will be added dynamically depending on the output of this rule
./bloup.sh "data/geneA.bam data/geneB.bam data/geneC.bam data/geneD.bam"

Dynamically updating jobs
Updating job b.
1 of 3 steps (33%) done
rule b:
    input: data2/geneD.bam, data2/geneA.bam
    output: results/gene_count.tsv

command
Touching output file results/gene_count.tsv.

2 of 3 steps (67%) done

localrule all:
    input: results/gene_count.tsv

3 of 3 steps (100%) done
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not exactly an answer to your question, but rather a suggestion to reach your goal. **

I think it's not possible - or at least not trivial - to modify a yaml file during the pipeline run.

Personally, when I run snakemake workflows I use external files that I call "metadata". They include a configfile, but also a tab-file containing the list of samples (and possibly additional information about said samples). The config file contains a parameter which is the path to this file.

In such a setup, I would recommend having your "rule a" output another tab-file containing the selected samples, and the path to this file could be included in the config file (even though it doesn't exist when you start the workflow). Rule b would take that file as an input.

In your case you could have:

```
config:
 samples: "/path/to/samples.tab"
 valid_samples: "/path/to/valid_samples.tab"
```

I don't know if it makes sense, since it's based on my own organization. I think it's useful because it allows storing more information than just sample names, and if you have 100s of samples it's much easier to manage!